# load gif until page is fully load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to **display** a **gif image** until the website is completely loaded. 
Once I click button **(onclick=window.open)** a new page opened but is **blank** and the **gif** is only appearing once the website is loaded.

I want once **clicking** the button a new page opened and showing immediately the gif and **disappear** once the page is loaded

Can anyone help me, **what** **I’m doing wrong** or what is missing **to load the gif** when the page is loading?  Here is my code, thank you so much

**land.php file:**

```
<button type="button"
        onClick="window.open('./gremo.cfm ',
                                     toolbar=no,
                                     menubar=no,
                                     scrolling=yes,
                                     scrollbars=yes
                                 ')">

</button>
```

**gremo.php file:**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHide(elementid){
            if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
                document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
            }
    }
    window.onload = function () { reSizeTextarea(); showHide('loadingd'); }
</script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="loadingd" align="center">
        <br/><br/><br/><img src="./loading.gif">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: well seems about right since only thing to load is the image so as soon as it loads, window.onload fires.

Comment: You can delay `showHide('loadingd')` by putting it in a setTimeout, i dunno, for about 250ms

Comment: @epascarello, thank you but what i can do, that the gif is loading during the page is loading and disappear once the page is loaded ?

Comment: @darklightcode, thank you.. can you show me this setTimeout, how it looks like ? thank you

Comment: function () { reSizeTextarea(); setTimeout(function(){showHide('loadingd');},250) }

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get the whole picture : you want the gif to appear during loading, or once a button is clicked ?

Comment: @LoneWanderer, once i click the button a new page opened. the new page is blank and once the page is loaded the gif display for 2 seconds. 
I want once i'm clicking the button a new page opened and showing immediately the gif and disappear once the page is loaded

Comment: @alex85 Well (to me) that should be stated that way in your question

Comment: @LoneWanderer, sorry for this... i'm new here.. next time i will make better.. thank you for your support, i corrected my queston

Comment: Once againL Your code says once the page loads, it hides the image. Since all that is on that page is that image. Once your loading image loads, onload fires. If you want to delay it, than you can add a timer `onload = function () { window.setTimeout(function (){ showHide('loadingd')}, 2000); }` but seems weird you want to add an artificial delay just to show an image.

Comment: @epascarello, maybe i explained wrong...  when i opened the page normally it should appear a gif in oder to show that the page is loading.. .in the moment the gif is not available.. so the page is blank... i want that the gif is display so that users know that the page is loading..

Comment: So do not hide it by default? Not sure what the issue is.... The image itself has to download and load. window.onload fires after all the content (included images) have been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a lot of content, it will take time to load. The image will show and than hide when the onload event happens. Now run it again, the content is cached and loading will take no time at all.

So load time depends on what there is to load/render, how it is loaded, and if it is cached or not.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("loading").remove()
  document.querySelector(".content").removeAttribute("hidden")
}
```

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none
}

#loading {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img id="loading" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7bu8sRnYpTOG1p8k/source.gif" />

<div class="content" hidden>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" />
</div>
```

In your example, you have nothing that takes time to load other than the loading image. So as soon as your image is loaded, the window.onload is triggered. That is why it flashes.

If you want the image to show, you can add some logic saying if I have not been here for X seconds, than wait....

```js
var startTime = new Date()
window.onload = function () {
  var loadTime = new Date()
  var diff = loadTime - startTime;
  if (diff > 5000) {
    toggleLoad()
  } else {
    window.setTimeout(toggleLoad, 5000 - diff)
  }
}

function toggleLoad () {
  document.getElementById("loading").remove()
  document.querySelector(".content").removeAttribute("hidden")
}
```

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none
}

#loading {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<img id="loading" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/3o7bu8sRnYpTOG1p8k/source.gif" />

<div class="content" hidden>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/300" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/400" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/500" />
</div>
```

To ensure the loading gif loads fast, on the parent page, you probably want to preload it

```
var img = new Image()
img.src = "your.gif"
```

Comment: thank you epascarello !! your solution is very good, 
when i open the a new page clicking the button the page is still blank and the gif is not displaying, only once the content is loaded... how can make the  possible that the gif is displaying once i click the button...

Comment: If it does not show up, than it is an issue with how you are adding the loading GIF... Your example should be fine, guessing what is in your post does not equal what you actually have.

Answer (score 1):

Note that when you are running locally, resources are loading fast.. very fast

Don't forget to use your developer tools and configure network throttling (to simulate a slower connection). That should simulate a "real" scenario and let you test your code better

Here is a screenshot from chrome... enjoy!

[image]